# SQL - How to keep the last row if it meets a condition, but remove other rows beforehand which meet the same condition

Tags: sql, databricks

I'm coming across an SQL issue which I could do with some advice on.

I have an example below showing actions taken between different energy suppliers for dispute cases. The `action_time_start` is when supplier 1 sends an action, and `action_time_end` is when supplier 2 sends a response.
The row number is not included in the main table but I have added it in here for visibility.

| dispute_id | supplier_1_action_sent | supplier_2_action_response | action_time_start | action_time_end | row_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 847294 | Proposal received (P) | Accept Proposal | 2023-01-23 | 2023-01-23 | 4 |
| 847294 | Agreement made (Y) | `NULL` | 2023-01-24 | `NULL` | 3 |
| 847294 | Agreement made (Y) | Close Dispute | 2023-01-25 | 2023-02-03 | 1 |
| 847294 | Proposal received (P) | `NULL` | 2023-02-3 | `NULL` | 1 |

I need to:

- Include columns 2 and 4 in the results.
- Include column 1 in the results (the last row), where the result for `action_time_end` is null.
- Remove column 3 from results, where `action_time_end` is null.

For the table overall, I need to remove any columns where `action_time_end` is null except for when it is the last row, for each dispute_id. I also need to keep all columns in the results where `action_time_end` is not null.

If the last row has a value in `action_time_end` which is not null then this needs to be kept in, and all rows before where it's null removed.

Any suggestions here?

I have tried a number of different solutions, including:

- Using `MAX(COALESCE(TO_DATE(action_time_end), DATE '9999-01-01'))` and filtered out instances where the action_time_start < action_time_end and action_time_end != '9999-01-01'.
- Including row_num and filtering `where row_num = 1 and action_time_end is not null`
- Doing a complex `CASE WHEN` in the last where clause of the query

The issue is that I'm not sure how to keep in the last row but remove all the others when a certain condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `CASE` expressions here:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN action_time_end IS NULL THEN dispute_id END AS dispute_id,
    supplier_1_action_sent,
    CASE WHEN action_time_end IS NOT NULL THEN supplier_2_action_response END AS supplier_2_action_response,
    action_time_start
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This has put me on the right path. This only gave 2x results, where action_time_end is null. However with a bit of tweaking and adding in row_num, I found the solution below:

 SELECT
        CASE WHEN action_time_end IS NOT NULL
       OR (row_num = 1 AND action_time_end IS NULL) THEN dispute_id END 
      AS dispute_id
    , supplier_1_action_sent
    , CASE WHEN action_time_end IS NOT NULL THEN act.action_taken END AS 
      supplier_2_action_response
    , act.action_time_start
    , act.action_time_end
  FROM my table